# Find the parametric equation of the line passing through the point $ \ (-3,4,1) \ $

Tags: geometry

Find the parametric equation of the line passing through the point $ \ (-3,4,1) \ $  parallel to the $ \ xy-plane \ $ and perpendicular to the $ \ yz-plane $ .

**Answer:**

Let the equation of the line  through $ \ (-3,4,1) \ $ is

$ \frac{x+3}{l}=\frac{y-4}{m}=\frac{z-1}{n} \ $

**But how to use the given conditions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These equations suppose you have a directing vector of the line, and if some coordinates of the directing vector are $0$, the corresponding numerator is $0$.

- Perpendicular to the $yz$-plane: a directing vector is $\vec u=(1,0,0)$.
- Parallel to the $xy$-plane: that is implied by  what the directing vector is.

So the parametric equations are
$\;\begin{cases}
x=-3+t,\\y=4,\\z=1.
\end{cases}$

Comment: can you explain again the condition that the line is parallel to the xy-plane

Comment: Well, a line is parallel to a plane if it is parallel to a line in the plane, or a directing vector of the line is collinear to a vector of the directing plane. It happens  that here, the directing vector  $\vec u$ is a vector of the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: A vector normal to $yz$ plane is, e.g., $\vec{n}=(1,0,0)=\vec{k}$.

Comment: so $ \ l \cdot 1+m \cdot 0 +n \cdot 0=0 \ \Rightarrow l=0 \ $  . But how to use the parallel condition

Comment: @MabudAliSarkar $l=0$ is not going to be helpful in $\frac{x+3}{l}$

Comment: @MabudAliSarkar In this case it is only to check. You know, that the line is described by $P_0+\vec{k}t$.

Comment: we have to use both the conditions

Comment: @MabudAliSarkar But a vector normal to $yz$ plane is parallel to $x$ ahis, so to $hy$ plane.